# Как зашифровать файл методом RSA

Tags: c#, шифрование, rsa

Подскажите пожалуйста Я как новичок в этом деле, хочу попробовать зашифровать файл методом [RSA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography.rsa(v=vs.110).aspx). Но не знаю с чего начать.

Хочу понять где можно хранить пароли для последующего шифрование и расшифровки.

**2**) Где лучше всего хранить пароль для шифрования и расшифровки?

**3**) Какой метод шифрования лучше подходит для файлов? Какой более лучше использовать?

Comment: 2) в голове пользователя 3) зависит от того, что вы хотите делать с файлами

Comment: @ГеннадийП, А может без приколов? Только по факту. Ну есть записи в файле, я хочу их просто зашифровать, сохранить куда-нибудь ключ, и после расшифровать по надобности.

Comment: На полном серьезе. Почитайте про виды шифрований. Есть симметричные и ассиметричные виды шифрований. Если хотите просто зашифровать файл для себя (чтобы никто его не прочитал) - вам нужен симметричный алгоритм, например AES. А ключ (или часть ключа) нужно всегда хранить в голове пользователя, ибо если его записывать полностью на компьютере - его можно вытащить.

Comment: Ладно это я понял, мне просто ребята посоветовали использовать rsa так-как он более надёжен.По поводу вытащить из файла я подумывал следующее, например: сохранить пароль где-нибудь на сервере у себя в так же шифрованном виде, и так же сначала расшифровать пароль и после сам файл.. В таком виде. Или же сохранить пароль на диске где-нибудь в секретном месте, и так же его зашифровать.

Comment: RSA не "более надежен", а он предназначен для других целей. Повторяюсь, для вас смысла нет использовать RSA, используйте AES. К тому же, использование RSA требует горааааздо больше вычислительных ресурсов.

Comment: @ГеннадийП, Хорошо, спасибо за ответ.